# I wrote a code to connect to wifi with SSID but I can't understand why it's not working

Tags: c#, wifi

It's a form application.

I'am using:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Security.Principal;
```

This is my code:

```
    Process NewProcess = new Process();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        NewProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        NewProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        NewProcess.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    }
```

Checks if the user is the administrator

```
    public bool IsUserAdmin()
    {
        bool isAdmin;
        try
        {
            WindowsIdentity user = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
            WindowsPrincipal principal = new WindowsPrincipal(user);
            isAdmin = principal.IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator);
        }
        catch(UnauthorizedAccessException)
        {
            isAdmin = false;
        }
        catch(Exception)
        {
            isAdmin = false;
        }
        return isAdmin;

    }
```

Stop broadcasting

```
    public void StopBroadcasting()
    {
        NewProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "netsh";
        NewProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "wlan Stop hostednetwork";
        try
        {
            using (Process execute = Process.Start(NewProcess.StartInfo))
            {
                execute.WaitForExit();
                SetLanDetails();
            }
        }
        catch
        {

        }
    }
```

Seting up lan details

```
    public void SetLanDetails()
    {
        NewProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "netsh";
        NewProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid="+textBox1.Text+" key="+ textBox2.Text;
        try
        {
            using (Process execute = Process.Start(NewProcess.StartInfo))
            {
                execute.WaitForExit();
                StartBroadcasting();
            }
        }
        catch
        {

        }
    }
```

Starting broadcasting

```
    public void StartBroadcasting()
    {
        NewProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "netsh";
        NewProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "wlan start hostendnetwork";
        try
        {
            using (Process execute = Process.Start(NewProcess.StartInfo))
            {
                execute.WaitForExit();
                buttonStart.Text = "Stop";
            }
        }
        catch
        {

        }
    }
```

Stop process

```
    public void StopProcess()
    {
        NewProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "netsh";
        NewProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "wlan stop hostendnetwork";
        try
        {
            using (Process execute = Process.Start(NewProcess.StartInfo))
            {
                execute.WaitForExit();
            }
        }
        catch
        {

        }
    }
```

Start button click

```
    private void buttonStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(buttonStart.Text=="Start")
        {
            StopBroadcasting();
            buttonStart.Text = "Stop";
        }
        else
        {
            StopProcess();
            buttonStart.Text = "Start";
        }

    }
```

I can't understand why it's not working. Did I forgot somthing? I didn't find a reason for this.

Comment: Someone know's why it's not working?

Comment: I would start from checking what trycatch clause actually catches...

Comment: I added MessageBox  after each piece of code and I can see that the code is done from the beginning to end.